# How to convert arguments to an array in coffeescript?

Tags: arrays, coffeescript

I have a function that should return all but the first argument

```
foo = -> arguments[1..]

foo(0,1,2,3,4)
```

unfortunately arguments is not an array but an object.

What is the best way to convert the object into an array?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a few CoffeeScript-ish options using a [splat](http://coffeescript.org/#splats) to take care of array-ifying `arguments`. You can use [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

```
f = (args...) -> args.slice(1)
```

[Demo](http://coffeescript.org/#try:f%20=%20%28args...%29%20-%3E%20args.slice%281%29%0Aconsole.log%28f%281,2,3,4%29%29%0A)

Or you could use a [range](http://coffeescript.org/#slices) instead of directly calling `slice`:

```
f = (args...) -> args[1..-1]
```

[Demo](http://coffeescript.org/#try:f%20=%20%28args...%29%20-%3E%20args%5B1..-1%5D%0Aconsole.log%28f%281,2,3,4%29%29%0A)

You can simplify the second version [because](http://coffeescript.org/#slices):

> Slices indices have useful defaults. An omitted first index defaults to zero and an omitted second index defaults to the size of the array.

So you could leave off the `-1` and say just:

```
f = (args...) -> args[1..]
```

instead. Thanks to [scar3tt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1880763/scarl3tt) for pointing this out.

Comment: @Wex: True but I think there's something to be said for the "I'm a variadic function" explicitness of `(args...)` that directly using `arguments` doesn't always give you.

Comment: interesting, the ```args...``` is essentially turned into ```[].slice.call(arguments)``` by the coffeescript compiler

Comment: CoffeeScript permits one or both indices in a range to be omitted ([source](http://coffeescript.org/#slices)). The `args[1..-1]` to me is a little needlessly confusing. My preference would be to use `args[1..]` instead.

I do acknowledge that this may not have been the case at the time the answer was written.

Comment: @scarl3tt: I think I missed that. The only relevant thing I can find in the ChangeLog is "Both endpoints of a slice are now allowed to be omitted for consistency, effectively creating a shallow copy of the list." and that was from 1.3.1 on April 10, 2012 (i.e. about a year before this answer). Let me patch things up a bit.

Answer (score 1):

You can ignore the first argument and use splats to capture the rest:

```
foo = (_, rest...) -> rest
```

You could also do something like `foo = (args...) -> args[1...]`, but that'll [compile to](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3afoo%20%3D%20%28args...%29%20-%3E%20args%5b1...%5d) two different calls to `Array#slice` ([unlike the first snippet](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3afoo%20%3D%20%28_%2C%20rest...%29%20-%3E%20rest)).

Comment: that is a great answer if I only want to ignore the rest of the arguments. I used the ```[1...]``` just to illustrate that I cannot do array operations...

Comment: @Michael_Scharf, ha, OK. Then yeah, the idiomatic way to treat `arguments` as an array in CoffeeScript is to simply declare the function as `(args...) ->` and then use `args` which is a real array.

Answer (score 0):

What found is to use `Array.prototype.slice`:

```
coffee> foo = -> Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments)[1..]
[Function]
coffee> foo(0,1,2,3,4)
[ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
```

Another version would be

```
[].slice.call(arguments)
```

Comment: You could use [`::`](http://coffeescript.org/#classes) instead of `prototype`: `Array::slice.apply...`